# delete item in a tuple in python

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, tuples

I have a file in this format

```
[('misure', 'di', 'protezione'), ('libertà', 'di', 'espressione', 'di', 'popolo')]
```

What I want is to eliminate from the tuple the preposition (di), and return the result in the same format. So I created this function to do this

```
lista = myfilelist
prep = prepositionfile
li = ast.literal_eval(lista)

 for i in li:
    word = str(i)
    ll = word.split("', '")
    for w in ll:
        lll= w.strip("('')")
        if lll in prep:
            i = word.replace(lll, "")
            i.strip('')

     print (nonlem(li))
```

but it return the tuple in this format

```
[('misure', '', 'protezione'), ('libertà', '', 'espressione', '', 'popolo')]
```

The output needed is

```
[('misure', 'protezione'), ('libertà', 'espressione', 'popolo')] ### without ''
```

Comment: @cdonts thats not necessarily a problem, you can always make a copy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ast.literal_eval` to turn the string into a list of tuples

```
>>> from ast import literal_eval
>>> l = literal_eval("[('misure', 'di', 'protezione'), ('libertà', 'di', 'espressione')]")
```

Then a list comprehension to make new tuples out of the first and last element

```
>>> [(i[0], i[-1]) for i in l]
[('misure', 'protezione'), ('libertà', 'espressione')]
```

Then `str` to create a string from the list of tuples

```
>>> str([(i[0], i[-1]) for i in l])
"[('misure', 'protezione'), ('libertà', 'espressione')]"
```

**Edit**
If you want to remove all instances of the string `'di'` it is the same idea, you can use a list comprehension

```
>>> [tuple(i for i in j if i != 'di') for j in l]
[('misure', 'protezione'), ('libertà', 'espressione', 'popolo')]
```

**Edit 2**
Even more generally, if you have a `set` of prepositions you want to exclude

```
>>> prepositions = {'di', 'a', 'al'}
>>> [tuple(i for i in j if i not in prepositions) for j in l]
[('misure', 'protezione'), ('libertà', 'espressione', 'popolo')]
```

Comment: Yes, but this an example, because the number of items in the tuple can be more than three

Comment: @gino Then show an example of a general case, or multiple cases. I can only work with what you tell us, I cannot read minds.

Comment: Oh, so you always want to remove the string `'di'`? Okay one sec.

Comment: No, non always 'di', it can be any other preposition

Comment: @gino Do you have a full enumeration of all prepositions?

Answer (score 1):

Tuple are immutable so you cannot change them once created. You can create new ones. Try this:

```
[tuple(j for j in i if 'di' not in j) for i in a]
```

[Here](https://ideone.com/khL5dL) is the working demo.

Answer (score 1):

```
[tuple(j for j in i if 'di' != j) for i in li]
```

I modified sam2090 code, since the string 'di' can be part of a word like 'dim'